# How do I assign hosts to classes in ISC DHCPD?

Tags: isc-dhcp, dhcpd

Suppose I have a bunch of hosts set up like this:

```
host host2 { hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx; fixed-address 192.168.1.2; }
host host3 { hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx; fixed-address 192.168.1.3; }
# etc ...   

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  option routers 192.168.1.254;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

  # Unknown test clients get this pool.
  pool {
    max-lease-time 1800; # 30 minutes
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.250;
    allow unknown-clients;
  }

  # MyHosts nodes get this pool
  pool {
    max-lease-time 1800;
    range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20;
    allow members of MyHosts;
    deny unknown-clients;
  }
}
```

I want to put these into a class and assign them to a pool so that I can ensure that only those hosts are allowed on that pool.

I tried defining them as:

```
class "MyHosts" {
  host host2 { hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx; fixed-address 192.168.1.2; }
  host host3 { hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx; fixed-address 192.168.1.3; }
}
```

But this gave an error "host declarations not allowed here".

How do I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you discovered, you cannot declare `host`s inside a `class`. The `class` declaration can only contain `match` or `match if` statements. If you want to group your client requests into classes using the `class` construct, you could do it something like this:

```
class "MyHosts" {
    match hardware;
}
subclass "MyHosts" 1:10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx;  # host2
subclass "MyHosts" 1:10:bf:48:xx:xx:xx;  # host3
```

In the above, the `match` statement in the `class` declares that subclasses will be matched by the `hardware` attribute. (`hardware` evaluates to the concatenation of the hardware type and the MAC address of the client; for ethernet clients, the hardware type is 1, thus the `1:` prefix in the data string of the `subclass` statements.)

When a client is a member of a subclass, it is also a member of the parent class, so now you can use `allow` and `deny` clauses in your `pool` declarations to ensure that members of `MyHosts` are assigned IPs from the desired pool, e.g.:

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
    pool {
        range 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.250;
        ...
        deny members of "MyHosts";
        ...
    }
    pool {
        range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20;
        ...
        allow members of "MyHosts";
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, does class and subclass will have any performance impact ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde "This is essentially a speed hack - the main difference between five classes with match expressions and one class with five subclasses is that it will be quicker to find the subclasses." https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-41-manual-pages-dhcpdconf#subclasses